# Jade Object iteration in Express+NodeJs Framework

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am using Node.js with Express framework and MongoDB. In my `index.js` file I have a route like this.

```
router.get('/adslist', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.collection('adscollection');
collection.find({},function(e,docs) {
  docs.each(function (err, docc) {
      if (docc) {
        console.log(docc);
      }
    });
  res.render('adslistpage', {userlist: docs});
  });
});
```

I am able to see the output in console  like this

```
{ "_id":"...", "adid": "1"}
```

But I am not able to iterate the object in Jade.

```
extends layout
block content
h1.
  User List
p=userlist
ul
  each user, i in userlist
     li #{user.adid}
```

Although `'p=userlist'` is printing `[object Object]` I am getting error in `'ul'`

```
Cannot read property 'adid' of undefined
```

Comment: Do all the documents have a field named `adid` ?

Comment: Yup. There are three documents and all have 'adid'